# UILabel to size automatically according to text size

Tags: ios, uilabel, text-size

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has two `UILabels` and one `UIImageView`. I set each `UILabel's` text based on data objects from a web service. So, until runtime there is no way of knowing the size of the text as it could be anything from my web service call.

Is there a way to tell `UILabel` to adjust its size automatically, according to its text size or content?

**UPDATE**

Okay for some reason all the suggested methods make no changes to my UILabel's at all in UITableViewCell.

I am setting the text in the code below:

Example using SujithPt's method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BBCategoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CategoryCell"];
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    BBFilterCategoryObject *category = self.categories[indexPath.row];

    cell.title.text = category.category.name;
        CGSize labelSize = [self getSizeForText:cell.title.text maxWidth:150 font:@"ChaparralPro-Bold" fontSize:15];

    [cell.title sizeThatFits:labelSize];

    return cell;
}


- (CGSize)getSizeForText:(NSString *)text maxWidth:(CGFloat)width font:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(float)fontSize {

    /*! Returns the size of the label to display the text provided
     @param text
     The string to be displayed
     @param width
     The width required for displaying the string
     @param fontName
     The font name for the label
     @param fontSize
     The font size for the label
     */

    CGSize constraintSize;
    constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
    constraintSize.width = width;
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:attributesDictionary
                                      context:nil];

                        CGSize stringSize = frame.size;

    return stringSize;

}
```

Comment: Use `UITextView` instead.

Comment: these Links may help you 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094753/how-to-adjust-and-make-the-width-of-a-uilabel-to-fit-the-text-size    2.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152262/iphone-adjust-uilabel-width-according-to-the-text

Comment: What happened to `sizeToFit`?

Comment: sizeToFit was not deprecated, check the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this method:

```
/*! Returns the size of the label to display the text provided
    @param text
        The string to be displayed
    @param width
        The width required for displaying the string
    @param fontName
        The font name for the label
    @param fontSize
        The font size for the label
 */
- (CGSize)getSizeForText:(NSString *)text maxWidth:(CGFloat)width font:(NSString *)fontName fontSize:(float)fontSize {
    CGSize constraintSize;
    constraintSize.height = MAXFLOAT;
    constraintSize.width = width;
    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize], NSFontAttributeName,
                                          nil];

    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                      options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                   attributes:attributesDictionary
                                      context:nil];

    CGSize stringSize = frame.size;
    return stringSize;
}
```

**Edit**

Set the label frame using the size returned from the above method.

```
[cell.title setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.title.frame.origin.x, cell.title.frame.origin.y, sizeFromTheMethod.height, sizeFromTheMethod.width)];
```

Comment: This appears to work - as stringSize is set correctly when stepping through the method. However my labels don't change size correctly. What am I missing?

Comment: Will you post your code where you setting the label properties with the question?

Comment: You are just calling the method I have posted. Use its returning size to set your label height.

Comment: I updated the question. Should I be doing it like that?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Labels remain the same, still.

Comment: Checked the xib file where I created the cell and set auto layout off / on. Still makes no difference.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Set the frame of the label as in the edit.

Comment: That seems like a step in the right direction. The cells change width - however it seems the method is not responding to font size - even if I set the font smaller, it stays the same size and the text is cut off still.

Comment: Set the text after setting frame.

Comment: Then all labels are exactly the same size as your method's string is always the same - the default text of UILabel. "Label" - if I set the text first - and go through the method - each stringSize has a different width. However for some reason its not long enough for the text that is in it. I'll try again stepping through it and see whats up. Appreciate your help dude.

Comment: I noticed in your method: attributesDictionary always has 0 key / value pairs. Is this by design?

Comment: The attributesDictionary is used for setting font attributes. It will contain the font details in this case.

Comment: The from was UiFont did not know what my custom font was - so it set it to nil.

Answer (score 2):

```
//use this for custom font
CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:
[UIFont fontWithName:@"ChaparralPro-Bold" size:40 ]}].width;

//use this for system font 
CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName
:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:40 ]}].width;

label.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, width,height);

//point.x, point.y -> origin for label;
//height -> your label height;
```

Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152262/iphone-adjust-uilabel-width-according-to-the-text)

Comment: sizeWithFont is deprecated in iOS 7.0.

Comment: +1 @RajPatil for making a smaller answer for this. Note there's a duplicate semicolon on the "use this for system font" part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue once.
What I did was...
created a class which represent UITableViewCell as well as cell configuration properties (height,width..etc)

```
class Cell{

 NSString * urlLabelString; //which will come from web service


 //it will return height of Cell which can be used in `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method
    -(float)height{

        //calculate size of label using [sizeWithFont][1]  method and add your image height here
        // and return total dynamic cell height
       return totalheight;
     }

}
```

you can keep array of these class objects as datasource for your UItableView

Hope it helps !