# How to align and move two labels programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I have to use two sequential label, like:

```
Title: New Title
```

But title is a localized string that change his length in different languages. How to programmatically move the UILabel of `New title` at the end of `Title` ? With autoLayout the old solutions found on StackOverflow don't seem to be working.

Comment: Show the code where you set whether the frame or the auto layout constraints.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152262/iphone-adjust-uilabel-width-according-to-the-text) out ,might be helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one string

```
  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title:%@   Newtitle:%@", Title, newtitle];
```

If color of title and text are different use attributed string like this example -

```
   NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:@"Its an test attributed string."];
    [str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor]       range:NSMakeRange(3,5)];
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor]      range:NSMakeRange(10,7)];
  [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(20, 10)];
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I am looking for. BTW iOS is kinda creepy to do this things :\

Answer (score 0):

set the second label frame after the first frame.
label2 x point will be label1 x point + lable1 length.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't work. With Auto Layout you can't set in `viewDidLoad` the frames.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just one label with text is formated:

mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", Title, newtitle];

Comment: Because the first part is in Light blue an bold, the second part in in red and normal font.

Comment: @fustalol then use NSAttributedString and you can set different colors for different ranges.

Answer (score 0):

try to add NSLayoutConstraints between the leading of label2 and trailing of label1 with the constant

```
value = 0;

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label2
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                     toItem:label1
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                 multiplier:1
                                                   constant:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
[label1 setText:@"I am label1"];
[label2 setText:@"I am label2"];

CGRect frame = label1.frame;

[label2 setFrame:CGRectOffset(frame, frame.size.width, 0)];
```